# How to find the derivative using natural logs?

Tags: calculus

[derive http://webwork.math.montana.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/equations/f8/914de36cdbb278cc1eb5309a2662301.png](http://webwork.math.montana.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/equations/f8/914de36cdbb278cc1eb5309a2662301.png)[take the derivative]

-since we have 'x' raised to a number, we must use natural log.

-I have the answer, but it is how to get there that confuses me.

[answer http://webwork.math.montana.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/equations/38/7e6ef64b2b4362a4cafb4df7b93a901.png](http://webwork.math.montana.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/equations/38/7e6ef64b2b4362a4cafb4df7b93a901.png)[answer]

-Things I have tried.

```
(1)Take the derivative first using the quotient rule, then use natural log.
(2)Take the natural log first, and then take the derivative.
```

**Thank you all for the help, here is how I solved it.**

if $f(x) = 4^x-6^{-x}$

and

if $g(x) = x$

Using the quotient rule $(f'(x)*g(x)- g'(x)*f(x)) \ / \ g(x)^2$

and $d/dx \ \ a^{f(x)} = a^{f(x)}*ln(a)*f'(x)$  rule for natural logs with $a$ being a constant.

```
breaking problem into small steps

take natural log of $4^x$
```

$ln \ of \ 4^x = 4^x *ln(4)*1$

```
now take the natural log of $6^{-x}$
```

$ln \ of \ 6^{-x} = 6^{-x} *ln(6)*-1$

```
so far the equation now looks like this.
this is f'(x) for the first part of the quotient rule
```

$4^x*ln(4)*(1)-6^{-x}*ln(6)*(-1)$

```
now we multiply all f'(x) by g(x)
```

$x(4^x*ln(4)*(1)-6^{-x}*ln(6)*(-1))$

```
now we subtract f(x)*g'(x) and we get
```

$x(4^x*ln(4)*(1)-6^{-x}*ln(6)*(-1)) - (1)(4^x-6^{-x})$

```
now we simply divide by g(x)^2 and we get the answer
```

$x(4^x*ln(4)*(1)-6^{-x}*ln(6)*(-1)) - (1)(4^x-6^{-x}) \ / \ x^2$

Comment: Perhaps you can include some of your intermediate steps, so that others can give you more relevant feedback?

Comment: alright I will work on that.

Comment: The answer is missing a closing parenthesis some where?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write that $4^x=exp(x ln(4))$ and $6^{-x}=exp(-x ln(6))$

after that, derivate using $(\frac{u}{v})'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$

and $(fog)'=g' f'og$